# Adding customizable Text to a Magento Page

Tags: javascript, magento

I've been tasked with trying to add a message to the Product Compare Page which will appear if the customer has, by some stroke of stupidity, been able to access the page when there are no products to compare

now i understand there a `<script type="text/javascript">window.close();</script>` already in there however it seems like it doesn't work if you open a new window and type in the URL (the equivalent to bookmarking the page, how i figure is that if i put this message above the `<script type="text/javascript">window.close();</script>` line, if the window doesn't close the customer will get the message.

Now that part is easy enough, the hard part is the second part to my task and that's allowing this text to be changeable though the blackened much like how you can change the Logo Image Alt in System > Configuration > Design > Header.

we already have some new section in System > Configuration thanks to some custom modules however i don't want to have to create an entire module just so a department we can't trust to edited the page and not stuff it up in the process can change one line of text

So is there a way to add customizable Text to a Magento Page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the javascript to `window.location = '/sorry-page';` or something like that and creat "sorry-page` as a CMS page. Otherwise you will need a custom module.

Comment: think i'll do the `window.location` thing since it does seem very wasteful on resources to make a module just for a line of text